# 503 Service Unavailable: Back-end server is at capacity ........? Do server receive my POST data?

Tags: php, http, httpwebrequest

After I posted my request ,
server give me 503 response,
I wonder if server have reveived my POST data ?

Comment: It depends. Maybe it did, maybe it didn't. I wouldn't count on it.

Answer (score 3):

The Web server (running the Web site) is currently unable to handle the HTTP request due to a temporary overloading or maintenance of the server. The implication is that this is a temporary condition which will be alleviated after some delay. Some servers in this state may also simply refuse the socket connection, in which case a different error may be generated because the socket creation timed out.

This is a server problem .
[From HTTP Error 503 - Service unavailable](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E503.html)

Answer (score -2):

What are you making the post with? A simple form?

If the server has given a 503, generally this means that there has been an error in the code or the server and no POST data could be received.

Please paste some server-side code so i can see if the error is in there.